# Chrooted drivers

Tags: xorg, drivers

1. If the host has the kernel drivers properly loaded, would the
   chrooted enviroment be able to use them (ex. wireless, power)?
2. Does the chrooted enviroment need its Xorg drivers to be configured or does
   it just need Xorg drivers from the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chroot is a very limited mechanism with poor isolation between the chrooted environment and the host. In fact, other than filesystem confinement due to modified root directory there is no other isolation at all. In particular all drivers compiled and loaded into the kernel are shared between the host and the chrooted environment. Note however that chrooted environment may be unable to access devices when `/dev`, `/sys` or `/proc` in the chrooted environment are different from host and don't include all the necessary files and/or device nodes.

Comment: will Xorg be shared?

Comment: You need to make sure that all files used by your Xorg are accessible under chroot environment. This can be done by copying or better by creating appropriate hardlinks (not symlinks). This will very likely include the UNIX-domain socket on which clients talk to the X server (note that you can create hardlinks to UNIX-domain socket normally). Check documentation, config files, strace output or simply error messages to find out the list of files you need to take care of.